# Is there a Stack Exchange site for history?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, site-proposal

Would anyone be interested in a history Q&A site on Stack Exchange to ask and talk about history?

For example, medieval, World War 1, World War 2, ancient times, coin collecting, stamp collecting (perhaps it would be more proper to have a Collectors site for those), etc. Just an idea.

Or does something like this already exist?

Comment: http://history.stackexchange.com/ or see the [original proposal on Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/5169/history).

Comment: Dang! Why isn't displayed at the bottom? Thanks!

Comment: Only fully launched sites are shown at the bottom. Beta sites are only shown at the bottom of other beta sites.

Comment: The sites on the bottom are ones out of beta. See this for the whole list of sites : http://stackexchange.com/sites

Comment: Yesterday is History , Tomorrow is a Mystery, and toda, today is Wednesday andI gotta study Thank You Very Much

Comment: In the future, if you can’t find a Stack Exchange site on your subject of expertise, we have a place called **[Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com)** where you can propose one. Discussing the prospects for a new site isn't really on topic here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The History site already exists: http://history.stackexchange.com**
It's still in public beta, so support and evangelize it to help it grow and reach critical mass!

In the future, visit [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) to view pending proposals for new sites, or even propose one of your own.
For reference, a complete list of sites is available in super-cool format on the [new Stack Exchange page](https://stackexchange.com/sites).